# gstreamer mp3 demuxer

Tags: gstreamer

Any Idea what demuxer should be used for mp3 ? I trying to implement [hello world](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-helloworld.html) program for playing an mp3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mp3 streams are usually not muxed. You will use a bitstream parser (such as mp3parse) and then a mp3decoder (such as mad).

Comment: Yes that is the recommended solution. Thought you want to build the pipeline manually.

Comment: Yeah I managed to get the pipeline up and running with the code as well. Since their hello world was using a demuxer I thought even mp3 would have one. I could not figure out one , So opted for decodebin2 \